# select cell in collection view after edit an uitextfield

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I try to select first cell in collection view after edit an uitextfield.

in function `func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)` call function `incandescenteCollection.selectItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0 , inSection: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally)` where incandescenteCollection is IBOutlet to collectionview.`@IBOutlet weak var incandescenteCollection: UICollectionView!`

But not work. Any Idea?

Comment: Where is said text field? Is it in a cell?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to read if you posted actual relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your controller has the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and the text field in question's delegate is set `self` (the controller).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ..., UITextFieldDelegate {

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var incandescenteCollection: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField! {
        didSet {
            // If the text field is in your cell,
            // move this line to cellForItemAtIndexPath
            // as cell.textField.delegate = self
            textField.delegate = self
        }
    }

    ...

    // MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

        incandescenteCollection.selectItemAtIndexPath(
            NSIndexPath(forRow: 0 , inSection: 0),
            animated: true,
            scrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally
        )
    }
}
```